# Make first sentence appear to the left of the other sentences until Enter is pressed

Tags: formatting, lyx

I would like to make something that looks like this:

[image]

Where each part of the text is a bit to the right of the first word of the first sentence and the line comes down only after I press "Enter".
How can I do such thing in lyx? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Okay found out the answer:
you can use [Alt + P D] for descriptions and you can (if you need to break a line) use [Alt+ I O R (char sequence)] or go to Insert->Formatting->Ragged Line break.